# Prove $\sqrt{2} \not \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt3]$

Tags: field-theory

Pretty simple problem but I'm having trouble finding the proof.

Numbers in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt3]$ are of the form $r+s\sqrt{3}$; $r,s \in \mathbb{Q}$.
I tried proving by contradiction. That is, assume $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt3]$ . Then, $\sqrt{2} = r+s\sqrt{3}$ $\rightarrow$ $2=r\sqrt{2}+s\sqrt{6}$. Then, since $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt6$ are both irrational, while $2,r,s$ are all rational, there will be some sort of contradiction. However, I'm not sure if this is right, and if it is, how to formalize it.

Comment: I think you should move $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ to the same side and then square the equation, which will leave only $\sqrt{6}$ and other rational parts. A contradiction. Of course, you have to mention that s is not equal to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an elementary proof, write
$$\sqrt{2} = r +s \sqrt{3}$$
$$\Longrightarrow\sqrt{2} - s \sqrt{3} = r$$
$$\Longrightarrow(\sqrt{2} - s \sqrt{3})^2 = r^2$$
$$\Longrightarrow2+3s^2-2s\sqrt{6} = r^2$$
$$\Longrightarrow \frac{2+3s^2-r^2}{2s}=\sqrt{6} $$

($s \neq 0$ because $\sqrt{2}$ is not an integer) which is absurd because $\sqrt{6}$ is irrationnal.

Comment: Excellent. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!