# Prove that $\sqrt[7]{2}\not\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{3})$

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I need to show that $\sqrt[7]{2}\not\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{3})$ but I have no idea how to do it. I've tried to reason with the extension degrees but I haven't got any satisfactory result.

Could someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: It goes like [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367013/prove-sqrt33-notin-mathbbq-sqrt32), or  [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3818766/prove-sqrt2-not-in-mathbbq-sqrt3?noredirect=1&lq=1), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9188/is-mathbbq-sqrt2-cong-mathbbq-sqrt3?noredirect=1&lq=1). You can also compute the field discriminants. Even better, use some concepts from ANT, see the comment below!

Comment: IMO the sleekest proof for this uses concepts from algebraic number theory. The prime ideal $(2)$ is unramified in $K=\Bbb{Q}(\root7\of3)$. Therefore $\root7\of2\notin K$. I also like Dietrich's suggestion to use discriminants.

Comment: Thank you @Watson for locating a suitable duplicate. GRJ, please comment on the theoretical tools available to you. Discriminants and ramification are often not covered in a first course on field theory. Yet, with higher order roots (here seventh) they give the simplest answers. Not ruling out the possibility of a proof using less technology.

Comment: We also have [this answer by orangeskid](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1575702/11619) that may help you.